# iphone, xcode; Reverse engineer a nib

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I was wondering if there is a way i can design a nib/xib file and generate code for that?
meaning, instead of writing lines of code to generate an interface, would'nt it be easier to design and nib file using IB and get the source or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may misunderstand what a nib file is.

If you mean that you'd rather create your view objects in interface builder and have outlets automatically inserted into your source files then look to XCode beta, it does that.

Comment: Actually, the non-beta version of Interface Builder already does this.  Create a nib and choose File -> Write Class Files.

Comment: yeah i just noticed this one, i have to see if it works, thanks a lot jsd

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible in xcode to generate code for a nib file designed.I know you are referring to web designing tools like macromedia dreamweaver.

Secondly why do you require the code?X code provides the facility to integrate the nib in the code itself.

Thanks

Comment: may be my thinking is wrong, correct me if i am, i would like to create a view or multiple copies of the same view (which is designed inside a nib file) at run time along with all the outlets and actions. In other words, each view i created at run time takes the outlets and actions from the nib file and works independently. I am not even sure if i said my question right.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a code generator, which as **jsd** noted IB will do if you really want.

However, your life will be a lot easier if you just accept what IB is, an object creation, placement, linking and storage mechanism.

IB is doing all the tedious stuff for you, creating instances and setting initial values for you along with (some) relationships, then compositing them all.  It freeze-dries the result so it's ready to go at runtime.

It does sometime make sense to use what IB has done as a template to base other code around instead of using the views it creates directly, but if you generate code then you are potentially out of sync with IB and it makes it hard to use for maintaining the interface going forward.

Comment: hi kendall, thanks for the insight; i did mention what i have in my mind in the above comment, can you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: One way would be to walk down the view hierarchy returned from loadWithNib, and create matching views and subviews - setting common things from each view like frame and background color and looking at the type to see if custom properties should be set.  You probably also could use NSCoder to freeze and create multiple copies of a view also, not sure if that is recursive as far as subviews go...

Comment: hmm, interesting, not sure how to start with it, but i think i understand what you mean; time for more reading :)